# Mapping function for an array

Tags: php, dictionary

I have an array like this `$a=("something","something else","another something");` and another array like this `$b=("b","bb")`.

I would like to produce an `$a = array("something"=>Array("b","bb"),"something else","another something");`. How can achieve this?

Comment: you want the first value from the first array to be the key for the 2nd array ?

Comment: So why don't you do it? `$a[$a[0]]=$b; unset($a[0]);`

Comment: What you are asking for is *not* concatenation in any way.

Comment: This is not a well-defined problem. Can you explain better?

Comment: so,you want to create multidimensional array ?

Comment: Manu Shioyaki - things move fast here on SO. When you ask a question you need to stick around for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for more flexibility:

```
function map_a_thing(key, val, compare) {
  if (key == compare)
    return array(key => val);
  else
    return key;
  end
}

$c = array_map('map_a_thing', $a, $b, 'something');
```

Consider that you're essentially asking a map-reduce question, where you seek a function to perform a given action upon a condition.

With this answer, you could iterate over your base array and re-map certain values

```
$map_targets = array('something', 'some2', 'some45', 'some-other');
foreach ($map_targets as $target) {
    $a = array_map('map_a_thing', $a, $b, $target);
}
```

See also, [array_reduce](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), and the generic [array_walk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this, there area many option either you can do this on the basis of the position or by the array element like the @Mike Moore answers

```
$a = array ( 'something', 'something else',  'another something');

$b = array('b', 'bb');

for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)
{
    if($i==0)
    {
        $a[$i] = array('something' => $b);
    }
}


print_r($a);
```

Answer (score -1):

**YIKES** my old answer was crap. Thanks for pointing it out *everybody*!

Here is my updated answer:

```
<?php

$a = array (
    'something',
    'something else',
    'another something'
);

$b = array('b', 'bb');

for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)
{
    if($a[$i] == 'something')
    {
        $a[$i] = array('something' => $b);
    }
}


print_r($a);
```

Comment: which would leave him with $a=("something","something else","another something", "something"=>Array("b","bb"));